# Creating and indexing arrays and matrices with byrow=TRUE

Tags: r, arrays

My homework questions are

[image]

My attempts are

```
A) VX<-(1:7)

B)VY<-matrix(1:7,7,7,byrow = T)
```

C)I am having trouble with this one since I'm not sure how to make byrow=T in an array

I have this V`Z<-array(1:7,dim<-c(7,7,7,byrow=T))` But this is not in the right format,

my professor hasn't taught us any other ways to do this.

I am new to R any help will be appreciated!

Comment: For the third one, the assignment for `dim` would be `dim = c(7, 7, 7)` or simply use `VZ <- replicate(7, VY)` and the last question solution is `VX[1]`, `VY[,1]` and `VZ[,, 1]`

Comment: you're amost there; after you have `VX <- 1:7` you can get `VY` by vector recycling of `VX`: `VY <- matrix(VX,7,7,byrow = TRUE)` and then recycle this to get `VZ` : `VZ <- array(VY,dim=c(7,7,7))`